Converting a multivariate linear correlation into a univariate one (predicting real estate prices in NY)
I am building a prediction model of real estate properties in New York based on a few inputs:

Area (size) of the property
Year it was built
Number of bedrooms
Number of parking spots

The data is being extracted from listings in Zillow. I plan on using something like 50 or 100 data points.
The idea is that by drawing a correlation between these variables and the properties' prices, I'll be able to predict the price of a new listing with some degree of accuracy.
Given that this involves using multiple inputs, which is outside my work scope (given I am doing that for school), I created a dummy variable (which I named k) weighting the correlation coefficient between the individual correlation coefficients and their sum, as shown below.
One way that I considered to restrict the analysis to a regular High school curriculum was to build individual linear correlations between my variables (area, number of bedrooms, etc.) and the price and, after that, use Pearson's correlation coefficient as percentages/weights when calculating the overall price.
In other words, Pearson's correlation coefficient would serve as a multiplying factor for each one of these entries/inputs.

Area (size) of the property: $\rho_a = 0.652$
Year it was built: $\rho_y = 0.606$
Number of bedrooms: $\rho_b = 0.318$
Number of parking spots: $\rho_p = 0.061$

Sum of the correlation coefficients: $\rho_a + \rho_y + \rho_b + \rho_p = 1.89$
With those weights in hand, I can then find the value for my dummy variable $k$ for each individual listing.
Example:
For a property with $195 m^2$ in size, built in 1988, and 3 bedrooms and 3 parking spots,
$$k = \frac{\rho_a \cdot 195 + \rho_y \cdot 1988 + \rho_b \cdot 3 + \rho_p \cdot 3}{\rho_a + \rho_y + \rho_b + \rho_p} = 189.5$$
Now, armed with all listing prices and all prices, I can build a regression for prices versus $k$.
For new listings, I would be calculating $k$ for it, and that would serve as the input of my pricing model.
In the spreadsheet I simulated a few predictions, some were off by $20\%$ and some by $320\%$. I wouldn't assume, however that these predictions would be very accurate, but mostly accurate.
The questions that I have
Is my idea of using Pearson's correlation coefficients valid? How could I make it more accurate?

It is great that you thought and built your own predictor by using only single linear regression. Your predictor seems reasonable, that is, predicating the price based on a single combined input generated based on the weighed sum of the inputs, where the weight of each input is proportional to its Pearson correlation with the price. However, I show your model cannot be optimal compared to available alternatives.
To simplify our discussion, assume that we have only two inputs $A$ and $Y$, and the joint distribution of the three random variables $P$, $A$ and $Y$ are fully known (this enables us to only focus on predictor structures, not statistical concerns).
Assume that we use the measure $\mathcal M(P, p(a,y))$ to quantify the deviation of the predictor $p(a,y)$ from price $P$  where $A=a, Y=y$ are given. There are many choices for $\mathcal M$ such as  $$\mathcal M(P, p(a,y))=\mathbb E \left( | P- p(a,y)|^p_
\,|A=a, Y=y\right )$$ for $p\ge1$, where note that for $p=1$ and $p=2$ we respectively get MAE and MSE measures. We always seek to find the best predictor $p^*(a,y)$ (if exits) by solving the following optimization problem:
$$ \min_{p} \mathcal M(P, p(a,y)). \tag {1} $$
For the MSE measure $$\mathcal M(P, p(a,y))=\mathbb E \left( ( P- p(a,y))^2 \,|A=a, Y=y\right ),$$ it can be proven that
$$p^*_1(a,y)=\mathbb E(P|A=a,Y=y), $$
known as regression of $P$ with respect to $A=a,Y=y.$
Now, let us define the linear predictor $$p_2(a,y)=\theta^*_0+\theta^*_1 \color{red}{a}+ \theta^*_2 \color{red}{y}$$ where $\theta^*_0$, $\theta^*_1$, and  $\theta^*_2$ are obtained by solving the following optimization problem:
$$ \min_{\theta_0, \theta_1, \theta_2} \mathcal M(P, \theta_0+\theta_1 a+ \theta_2 y) \tag {2}. $$
For the MSE measure, $p_2(a,y)$ is called multiple linear regression, which coincides with best predictor $p^*_1(a,y)$ obtained from (1) if the three variables $P$, $A$ and $Y$ follow a joint normal distribution (that is, both (1) and (2) yields the same predictor), given by
$$p_1(a,y)=p_2(a,y)= \mu_P+\sigma_P\frac{\sigma_Y (\color{red}{a}-\mu_A) (\rho_{PA}-\rho_{AY} \rho_{PY} )+ \sigma_A (\color{red}{y}-\mu_Y) (\rho_{PY}-\rho_{AY} \rho_{PA}
)}
{\left(1-\rho_{AY}^2\right) \sigma_A \sigma_Y}.$$
Note that your predictor is also a linear predictor. In fact, your predictor is a single linear regression of $P$ with respect to $K=k$ where  $K=\frac{\rho_{PA}A+\rho_{PY}Y}{\rho_{PA}+\rho_{PY}}$, with the following structure:
$$p_3(a,y)=\beta_0+ \beta_1\left (\frac{\rho_{PA}\color{red}{a}+\rho_{PY}\color{red}{y}}{\rho_{PA}+\rho_{PY}}\right ).$$
When the three variables has a joint normal distribution, your predictor $p_3(a,y)$ is given by
$$p_3(a,y)= \mu_P+\sigma_P\rho_{PK}\frac{\color{red}{k}-\mu_K }
{ \sigma_K}, \color{red}{k}=\frac{\rho_{PA}\color{red}{a}+\rho_{PY}\color{red}{y}}{\rho_{PA}+\rho_{PY}}$$
where $\rho_{PK}$, $\mu_K$, and $\sigma_K$ only depend on the parameters, which can be obtained simply based on $K=\frac{\rho_{PA}A+\rho_{PY}Y}{\rho_{PA}+\rho_{PY}},$ (but have complex expressions).
Now we are ready to give our main result:

For arbitrary deviation measure $\mathcal M$, your predictor $p_3(a,y)$ cannot outperform $p_1(a,y)$ or $p_2(a,y)$.

The above follows from the simple fact that $p_3(a,y)=\beta_0+ \beta_1\left (\frac{\rho_{PA}a+\rho_{PY}y}{\rho_{PA}+\rho_{PY}}\right )$ has a special linear structure (less flexible compared to $\theta_0+\theta_1 a+ \theta_2 y$), which limits it to be optimal for (1) or (2).
Working with $p_1(a,y)$ is not simple in practice (but under some normality assumptions it coincides with $p_1(a,y)$). Thus, it is better to use the linear predictor $p_2(a,y)$  instead of your predictor (recall that it is called multiple linear regression when using the MSE deviation measure).

Hope the above answer helps you to see why your predictor is not the best available choice.

Thank you for your help @Amir, have a great week

@bru1987 You are welcome!

No, unfortunately this is not a valid procedure. The first sanity check you should always perform when you propose a formula like yours is to see if the dimensions and units make sense. Unfortunately, your formula does not pass this test. E.g. if you were to change the units for price to, say, cents, then the correlations will remain the same, as will your predictions, which should in reality be multiplies by 100.
More precisely, correlations are unitless quantities. Your predictors each have units: area has $m^2$, year is unitless, and number of $X$ are counts. When multiplied by correlations, these units do not change. Adding quantities with different units (and thus different scales) finally makes no sense. This is true in physics, where you do not add speeds with energies or wavelengths. In your example you shouldn't add units of areas with units of rooms.
Instead, I encourage you to look at linear regression which will account for the unit conversion as well as the interactions of your predictors.

Hello @Jose, thank you for your input. Could you please elaborate more on your last paragraph? I did not quite grasp it. Thank you.

@bru1987 I meant that you should study linear regression, which is precisely the tool that should be used in this situation

that is exactly my point, as combining these regressions is the issue right now. As you can see, I've created the individual regression lines (all with respect to price), which shows that I can carry those out individually. However, in this situation how (if possible) can I combine them to create a model that considers all those inputs (area, year...)?

@bru1987 Like I said, you have a units problem with your current method, which is why it doesn't make sense. You also don't have regression lines, you have correlations. If you actually had regression coefficients, adding the terms you obtain in bivariate regression would be suboptimal.

@bru1987 Like I said, the solution to the problem you are looking for is linear regression, which will allow you to regress the price on all the predictor variables. See e.g. https://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/mreg/15/lectures/14/lecture-14.pdf
